# Scale y-axis for really small numbers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to scale the y-axis so my errorbars can be seen.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Here is my current code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# if using a Jupyter notebook, include:
%matplotlib inline

x = ntermsList
y = allPmuCycleCountAverages
xerr = 0
yerr = allPmuCycleCountStandardDeviations

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.errorbar(x, y, xerr=xerr, yerr=yerr,fmt='-o')

ax.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y-axis')
ax.set_title('Line plot with error bars')

ax.set_xticks(ntermsList)
ax.set_xticklabels(ntermsList)
ax.set_yticks(allPmuCycleCountAverages)

ax.yaxis.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

I've tried these solutions, but no joy:

```
plt.ylim(-1, 1)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

plt.yticks(np.arange(min(y), max(y)+0.5, 0.01))
```

I was expecting the y-axis scale to zoom close enough to the points so my errorbars could be seen

Comment: You could log-plot it?

Comment: If you zoom close enough, part of your data will be off-chart

Answer (score 0):

Try autoscalling based in y ticks. Here I'm adding some logic that just rescales the y-axis based on the data that is in the visible x-region. As I don't have your data I took random data.

```
import numpy as np
import random
ntermsList = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(555,))
allPmuCycleCountAverages = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(555,))
allPmuCycleCountStandardDeviations = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(555,))
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# if using a Jupyter notebook, include:
%matplotlib inline

x = ntermsList
y = allPmuCycleCountAverages
xerr = 0
yerr = allPmuCycleCountStandardDeviations

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.errorbar(x, y, xerr=xerr, yerr=yerr,fmt='-o')

ax.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y-axis')
ax.set_title('Line plot with error bars')

ax.set_xticks(ntermsList)
ax.set_xticklabels(ntermsList)
ax.set_yticks(allPmuCycleCountAverages)
#plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=90, horizontalalignment='right')
ax.yaxis.grid(True)


margin =0.1
def get_bottom_top(line):
    xd = line.get_xdata()
    yd = line.get_ydata()
    lo,hi = ax.get_xlim()
    y_displayed = yd[((xd>lo) & (xd<hi))]
    h = np.max(y_displayed) - np.min(y_displayed)
    bot = np.min(y_displayed)-margin*h
    top = np.max(y_displayed)+margin*h
    return bot,top

lines = ax.get_lines()
bot,top = np.inf, -np.inf

for line in lines:
    new_bot, new_top = get_bottom_top(line)
    if new_bot < bot: bot = new_bot
    if new_top > top: top = new_top

ax.set_ylim(bot,top)



plt.show()
```

Before Rescalling

[image]

After rescalling

[image]